# Bring widget to front in flutter on touch

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I am very new to Flutter and i am coming from Android development and i would like to do something equivalent to the `bringToFront()` method to put a `Widget` on top of the "View hierarchy", above the others.

I have 5 `Widget`s on the same page displayed next to each other and when i touch one of them i would simply like to display it in full screen above the others.

I am using the `Stack` widget so far but the order is fixed by the `Widget`s positions within the `Stack` and i have tried using a dynamic `List<Widget>` updated in the `onPressed()` method of each widget. This is very laggy and not what i want.

Is this possible to achieve a very simple `bringToFront()` when any `Widget` is touched in Flutter ?

**EDIT** :

To specify a bit better my structure :

As far as i know the `Navigator`, it will go to a new page and the animation may not be smooth.

What i have is 4 `Container` in each angle of the phone + one centered in the middle with a scaled size of 30% of the phone's width.

When i click on one of them, i want to scale it from 0.3 to 1 for a smooth animation and especially **make it above all of the others** because it is selected.

**UPDATE :**

My problem with the simple tap gesture is solved by the HeroWidget as @yellowgray suggested.

But i also need to have the scaling of the widget following my finger (GestureDetector). And in this case, the widget is still under others when it grows...

The question is really about making a Widget above others when your finger touches it on the screen, no matter which gesture is performed after.

Comment: Can you please share an example of the size of your Widgets? Because if they occupy the entire screen, maybe you can use `Navigator` directly. If not, then, I will have a look at what you mean and will provide a proper code. Also, please share your code that you used.

Comment: I edit the question to answer your comment it will be better.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [Hero Widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

Comment: Yes, Hero WIdget will work very well for you.

Comment: I have looked in the documentation and it seems really appropriate. i will learn more about it and Animations in Flutter in general, thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the global answer in this post : [Flutter Stack change depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031608/flutter-stack-change-depth)

The trick is to use the `GlobalKey()` method to identify the `Widgets` you want to bring to front. In my tests i was creating a new instance.

Hope this helps others.